When using WINDOWS-ROOT for the trust store no trusted certs found
I have a JAVA desktop application that is configured to use WINDOWS-ROOT for the trust store.  Using the flags -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=access:stack i see the following log
trustStore type is : WINDOWS-ROOT
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
default context init failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Attempting to see if it was a system wide issue I developed a C# application to call the same URLs using HttpClient.GetAsync().  These calls do not fail and I returned to my application to see if I could reproduce the issue.  The issue no longer exists and I see the following in the log where it shows numerous certificates now.
trustStore type is : WINDOWS-ROOT
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: *** (omitting) 
  Issuer:  ***
  Algorithm: ***
  .
  .
  .

We have been able to reproduce this behavior on a handful of systems. Why does the certificate store now populate? Any insight would be appreciated.

Is the server properly supplying its certificate chain?  WINDOWS-ROOT normally only contains root CA certs.  If the server only supplies its own cert and omits the intermediate certs, there's no way to connect the server's cert to the proper root CA.  Some systems may have installed the server's intermediate cert(s) into WINDOWS-ROOT.
